# python- how to find same words in two different excel workbooks

Tags: excel, windows, python-2.7

I want to find the same words in two different excel workbooks. I have two excel workbooks (data.xls and data1.xls). If in data.xls have the same words in the data1.xls, i want it to print the row of data1.xls that contain of the same words with data.xls. I hope u can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that both excel sheets have a list of words, with one word in each cell.

The best way to write this program would be something like this:

1. Open the first excel file, you might find it easier to open if you export it as a CSV first.
2. Create a Dictionary to store word and Cell Index Pairs
3. Iterate over each cell/word, add the word to the dictionary as the Key, with the Cell Reference as the Value.
4. Open the second excel file.
5. Iterate over each cell/word, check if the word is present in the Dictionary, if it is, you can print out the corresponding cells or store them however you want.